# VBScript for creating local account and adding to admin group used to work prior to logout / login to test newly created account:

Tags: vbscript

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

Set objEnv = objShell.Environment("Process")
strComputer = objEnv("COMPUTERNAME")
strUser = inputbox("Enter the username for the new admin account.")
strPass = inputbox("Enter the password for the new account.")

Set colAccounts = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & ",computer")

Set objUser = colAccounts.Create("user", strUser)

objUser.SetPassword strPass

Const ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = &h10000
objPasswordExpirationFlag = ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD
objUser.Put "userFlags", objPasswordExpirationFlag

objUser.SetInfo 

Set Group = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/Administrators,group")
Group.Add(objUser.ADspath)
```

Answer (score 3):

Sigh. A simple matter of "Run as Administrator".